# ProgressDialog doesn't dismiss with multiple instances of Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have one Asynctask in this app where I have a ProgressDialog in onPreExecute.

```
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Synchronization.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Please Wait</b><br/>Working..."));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }
```

And, in onPostExecute, I dismiss this dialog.

```
                    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Object> allShopsData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(allShopsData);

        final ArrayList<Object> allShops = allShopsData;

        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ExpandableListView expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandlist);

                expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
                expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
                expandableList.setClickable(true);

                MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(taskList,
                        allShops);

                adapter.setInflater(
                        (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),
                        Synchronization.ref);
                expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

    }
```

I start the Asynctask with name 'task1' in Synchronization( my Main Activity) onCreate().
Now, I have a Menu in the MainActivity where I cancel the Asynctask referred to by 'task1' and create another instance of Asynctask assigning it to 'task1'.

```
                task1.cancel(true);
                task1 = new GetShopsTask();
                task1.execute(taskList);
```

But here, I see one progress dialog created that dismisses after onPostExecute (I can also see my view updated in the background) but immediately after this, another progress dialog pops up which doesn't get dismissed.
Not sure, what part is causing this. Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm not sure this is causing your problem but please remove `runOnUiThread` from `onPostExecute()`. It is unnecessary as `onPostExecute()` runs on the `UI Thread` and it can cause problems/confusion

Comment: Where are you defining the `ProgressDialog`? Could it be that the two `AsyncTask`s interfere with one another and that the second one overrides the `pDialog` reference of the first one?

Comment: codemagic- I removed runOnUiThread from my code just now, but still the same behavior.

Comment: SimonSays- I have tried defining it as an instance variable as well as local to Asynctask. It's not making any difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is when you cancel AsyncTask, onPostExecute is not called and onCanceled() is called instead. See AsyncTask source.

```
private void finish(Result result) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            onCancelled(result);
        } else {
            onPostExecute(result);
        }
        mStatus = Status.FINISHED;
    }
```

So your progress dialog does not dismiss because onPostExecute is never called. You can solve the problem with adding this to your async task:

```
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
             // dismiss the dialog on canceled task
             if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```